Не получается подключится к WebSocket: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed
Я пытаюсь сделать онлайн мессенджер. Сам сайт работает, но когда пытаюсь подключится к WebSocket ничего не работает и выводит в консоль браузера следующее:

"WebSocket: sendmessage.js:27 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed:"

Сервер:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'html')));

//app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'html/index.html'));
//});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('websocket connected');
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('got message: ', message);
    ws.send('message from server!')
  })
  ws.send('succesfuly connected to websocket')
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`started on port: ${PORT}`);
});

Клиент:
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');//сюда ругается консоль
ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('conected to websocket');
    ws.send('test message!');
};
ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log('message from server: ', event.data);
};
ws.onclose = () => {
    console.log('websocket closed');
};
ws.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('websocket error:', error);
};


А вас не смущает, что express и websocket -тся на одном порту и не "женаты"? Есть для этого и готовое решение, но я бы посоветовал начать с простого тыц, а уж потом решать нужен ли вам express-ws.

@stylok Спасибо!

Получилось? Не моё дело советовать не зная вашей задачи, но я лично расширение не использую, а выношу вебсокеты в сторону от маршрутов express-а оборачивая handleUpgrade в условие if (request.url.startsWith('/chat')) {  wss.handleUpgrade(...)  }
